# Magic constants separator php on iis

Tags: php, iis, yii

I am running PHP on an IIS and I am having trouble with magic constants

I wish to use a framework(YII) which has alot of the following:

```
require(__DIR__ . '\..\vendor\autoload.php');
```

Problem is that this returns:

```
G:\PleskVhosts\***.com\api\web/../vendor/autoload.php
```

Which causes obvious problems

So I was wondering if there was a way to configure PHP so that the magic constants always return with `/` (To my understanding IIS/Windows accepts both back-slash and forward-slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it matters if you use / or \ in file paths, Windows usually works with both. It won't work with a single backslash though, you need to double backslash it in your code to escape the backslash if that makes sense. Try running...

`var_dump(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'));`

If it returns true then there shouldn't be a problem. Otherwise double check the file path is actually correct. You can also use `realpath` to translate the `/../` into a full path first.